# Xed : highlight selected text occurences?

Tags: linux, editors, text, syntax-highlighting, select

I'm using Gnome Xed text editor.
Is there a way to auto select all occurrences of currently selected-text across the document.

If Xed cant do it, what other linux text editor can do it  ? How ?

Comment: what do you plan to do after all occurrences are selected? do you really need to select them to do whatever you need to do? Sublime would automatically **highlight** other occurrences of selected-text.

Comment: just for visual inspection ... otherwise is hard to follow

Comment: In that case, you need the editor to **highlight** the other occurrences for you, not **select**. Sublime would do that for you.

Comment: installed it, 10x ... works, but it just [box-surround] the other occurrences... is there a a way to highlight them with different color